# How to display flex state elements?

Tags: flex3, mxml

I am tying to create a login form which returns if login was successful or not.
I created two states and added forms to them. But how to display them in mxml?

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="log">

        <mx:AddChild>
        //i add form here
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>

    <mx:State name="notlog">

        <mx:AddChild>
        //i add other form here
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
```

```
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" styleName="dark">

</mx:VBox>
```

How to display state within above Vbox? If I try to place state within Vbox I get an error that state can't be placed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try The following one code. you need little bit of modification in it..

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="log">
        <mx:AddChild>
            <mx:Label text="child 1 Selected" />
            //Write down the Codde here for log
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>

    <mx:State name="notlog">
        <mx:AddChild>
            <mx:Label text="child 2 Selected" />
            //Write down the Codde here for notlog
        </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>

<mx:VBox width="100%" height="70%" styleName="dark">
    <mx:Button label="Child1" click="currentState = 'log';" />
    <mx:Button label="Child2" click="currentState = 'notlog';" />
</mx:VBox>
```

For more information visit following link

[Click to open link](http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/mx/states/State.html)

Have a nice day...

Comment: no this is not what I want.I need to switch look of component depends of the result of validation function and i want  notlog to be currentState when app starts. <mx:VBox width="100%" height="70%" styleName="dark" currentstate="notlog"> throw error that notlog is unknow